# java.nio.file.FileSystemNotFoundException with spring app jar

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have a spring boot application which depends on another jar, say A. A needs some files in a bean, say MyBean. So I have placed those files in project's resources folder and with following code in bean's constructor I get hold of their path which I then set into A's bean.

```
URL res = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("fileNeededByMyBean.dat");
File file = Paths.get(res.toURI()).toFile();
String absolutePath = file.getAbsolutePath();
....use absolutePath in bean....
```

In IDE like IntelliJ, project runs fine. But when I try to launch it using 'java -jar app.jar' command, it fails with error:

```
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [x.y.z.MyBean]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.nio.file.FileSystemNotFoundException
```

How to get it working?

Answer (score -1):

Jar-file is essentially zip-archive. And java can not treat item of zip-archive as file.
To read resource form jar-file use:
`this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("fileNeededByMyBean.dat");`
Write data from resource into temporary file, then use its absolute path.

Comment: Bean is from legacy project and hence I need to pass absolute file path to it. I was thinking of passing file path as command line arguments, but not sure if this works.